# Embedding outlook calendar to webpage

Tags: javascript, outlook

It is obviously clear to me after going through outlook documentation that I can generate a html link of my OUTLOOK calendar and embed it to any webpage. This works fine when i create my iframe as below

```
<iframe width="900" height="500" src="https://cpgd-ab67acdd3e1c401a.calendar.live.com/calendar/private/blalaba-balajahhhdh-342d-4cea-ad46-25433581e015/index.html"></iframe>
```

and insert it into my EXISTING page with contents. My problem here is: After the page loads it redirects/navigates the parent window/page and completely replaces my DOM with a full outlook calendar. My intention is simply to put it in a particular section of my page (precisely a DIV).

**I HAVE TRIED**

1. sandboxing the iframe with the new HTML5 sandbox attribute. On the
   console, it throws errors.
2. I have also tried using ajax to load the iframe seperately. same
   error and failure.

I'm sure this action is deliberate by
    microsoft. I need a way to bypass this.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you a little I used this when I was sharing my calendar on a website, you can configure the CSS as you wish

```
<style unselectable="on">
#wrap {
width:1000px;
height:900px;
padding:0;
position:relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#frame {
width:1000px;
height:900px;
position:relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
}
#frame {
-ms-zoom:0.7;
}
</style>
<div id="wrap" unselectable="on">
    <iframe id="frame" src="[paste in here the link that outlook.com provides for you ... in between the quotes and without the brackets]"></iframe>
</div>
```